# Vector drawables in BottomNavigationView menu causes error

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to use vector drawables as icons of BottomNavigationView like following:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_incoming"
        android:icon="@drawable/incoming_background"
        android:title="Incoming"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_outgoing"
        android:icon="@drawable/outgoing_background"
        android:title="Outgoing"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_important"
        android:icon="@drawable/favorite_background"
        android:title="Favourite"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_background"
        android:title="Settings"/>

</menu>
```

And my drawables are like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_incoming_active"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_incoming_inactive"/>
</selector>
```

`@drawable/ic_incoming_active` and `@drawable/ic_incoming_inactive` are both vector drawables.

I am also using  `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

and

`implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1"`

But I am getting

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_incoming_active.xml from drawable resource`

Comment: I have the same problem on ice-cream sandwich API 15,
And when i converted it to PNG images it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the drawable `ic_incoming_active.xml` can't be found.  
In most cases the reason is that you have stored this drawable in a folder like `drawable-v21` and not in `res/drawable`.